# Android database not working on real device

Tags: android, database

I created signed apk of my application in android studio.
I installed apk in my phone. When I run it, the database data is not getting displayed.
The data is getting displayed in emulator. How to check database data in real device.

Database is stored in data/pkg/databases.
Thanks.

Comment: Has your device rooted?

Answer (score 1):

> How to check database data in real device.

the app should be debuggable ,try this way :

```
​Create a *.bat file and copy the following scripts ​​

adb shell run-as [package] chmod 777 /data/data/[package]/databases/

adb shell run-as [package] chmod 777 /data/data/[package]/databases/[db_file_name]

adb shell cp /data/data/[package]/databases/[db_file_name] /sdcard/

adb pull /sdcard/[db_file_name]

​Change [package] to the desired application package

Change [db_file_name] to the desired db name Run the bat file and you should see the copied database in the same folder as the bat file
```